# NextJs Auth0 - get user_metadata from user session middleware

Tags: next.js, auth0, next-auth

i'm trying to get a `user_metadata` from the `useUser` hook. Here is what i've tried.

**Auth Action**

```
exports.onExecutePostLogin = async (event, api) => {
  const namespace = 'https://my-tenant-auth0.com';
  api.idToken.setCustomClaim(`${namespace}/user_metadata`, event.user.user_metadata);
  api.accessToken.setCustomClaim(`${namespace}/user_metadata`, event.user.user_metadata);
};
```

**NextJs Middleware.**

```
const afterCallback = (req, res, session, state) => {
   session.user.idToken = session.idToken;
   session.user.testVar = JSON.stringify(session);

   return session;
};
```

No `user_metadata` in session variable.
Also when i `console.log(session)` inside `afterCallback` for some reason the `console.log()` isn't printing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually working, i was just missing one step which is 'activating' the action. On the dashboard under *actions/flows/login/*.
Drag and drop the action.
[image: dashboard screenshot]